# Masked Input Plugin jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am goting to use this [plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for an asp.net textbox.

The textbox is:

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Phone") %>' />
```

I want the format is (999) 999-9999 when the textbox is non-empty. But it is null when the textbox is empty.

I want to select different mask by the text.
How is the code like?

I tried below:

Thanks.

```
  jQuery(function($){  
    if(document.getElementById("<%# txtBox.ClientID %>")).innerText =
       $("<%# txtBox.ClientID %>").mask("(999) 999-9999");  
    else
      $("<%# txtBox.ClientID %>").mask("");
  });
```

**UPDATE**

The textbox is inside a gridview. It likes:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OrgContactPhone" SortExpression="OrgContactPhone">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrgContactPhone") %>' MaxLength="50">
                </asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Phone") %>' class="MaskText" />


$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = $('.MaskText');
    if ($.trim(obj.val()).length !== 0) {
        obj.mask("(999) 999-9999");
    }
    else {
        obj.mask("");
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to select different mask by the text..? can u give me some three examples...

Comment: Two masks are enough. But see the updated. I have to get the correct textbox id.

Comment: cssClass or class. I think that should be "cssClass".

Comment: if u use class it is giving error?. yes then run the code in browser right click view source page in that cssClass is converted in to class.. check this and tell me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12265/discussion-between-thulasiram-and-love)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I could be wrong but I don't think "`if(document.getElementById("<%# txtBox.ClientID %>")).innerText =`" will work due to how ASP.net works.

Secondly ASP.net has built in masking components.

Thirdly you could try this.

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    //Code function here to detect on text change for the textbox
    {
    if(document.getElementById("<%# txtBox.ClientID %>").innerText != "")
       $("<%# txtBox.ClientID %>").mask("(999) 999-9999");  
    else
      $("<%# txtBox.ClientID %>").mask("");
    }
  });
```

Comment: It will prob be easier to do this using the built in .net. The code above is just an example on how it works, but I am pretty sure asp.net controls change how they render when run in browser for example names and such.

Comment: I got an exception: The name 'txtBox' does not exist in the current context. The textbox is inside a gridview edit template.